# Error while creating robovm bindings for realm.io

Tags: robovm

I am trying to create robovm bindings for realm.io using bro-gen. I am getting the following error

> `resolve_type': Failed to resolve type 'int * __nullable' with kind
>   type_unexposed defined at :0:0 (RuntimeError)

when i run bro-gen.rb for the yaml file at http://pastebin.com/c4tWMQ28

Also if the list of headers only contains Realm.h nothing happens. So I am listing each header file.